# indicator for two AC power sources

Tags: ac, indicator

I would like to know if there is something like AND gate logic for two AC power sources i.e, if two of the sources are on the light will turn on else it will stay off .Thanks

Comment: Can you draw a schematic to clarify what you mean? All I can get out of your description is that you have a light with two separate power sources, and it should only turn on if both power sources are on. Is that really what you meant?

Comment: I just realized you might have meant "if two of the sources are on, the light will turn on". That seems more likely. The comma in the wrong place is really confusing. If this is what you mean, let me know and I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Yes that's correct sorry about the comma

Comment: It's called a relay.

Answer (score 0):

[image: AC voltage detector]
Try something like this... R1 and R2 must be like 50:1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 AC relays specified for the voltage of the sources. Then wire the contacts in series and you will get a switch that is ON only when both AC sources are ON and both relays are ON.

Comment: Actually there is a simpler way: one AC source powers the relay, the other on the indicator. Only if both are on you get power to the indicator and power to the relay that turns on the indicator.